# Adding Column Headers to excel extract in python

Tags: python

I have an extract in CSV and the content in the file is as bold and as accurate as it can get.
But there are no column headers when the content is extracted from the database.
Below is the code I am using for the extract.

Comment: Hello Phraseassembler, you have posted no code... Could you update your post?

Comment: conn = cx_Oracle.connect('Fatman', 'potbelly()', 'sractcane:1521/Stract')
#print(conn.version)

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('select first_name,last_name from people order by 1')
    file = open("file.xls", "w")
     for row in cur:
     file.write(row[0] + ',' + row[1] + '\n')
    file.close()
cur.close()
conn.close()
print("File successfully exported")

Comment: im so sorry the formatting was giving me problems when I was trying to add the code.ill make sure I do it that way the next time for everyone's sake